# Why would HLS stream distort in Stagefright 1.2 when ts files change?

Tags: android, video, http-live-streaming, distortion, stagefright

I've set up `Apache 2.0` with several `.m3u8` files serving a set of `mpeg2ts` files over `HLS`.  These `ts` files were produced with `libavformat` by `transmuxing` an `MP4` I downloaded from `youtube`.  When I play the resulting `HLS` on `VLC` or `QT`, everything works fine.  But on Android (Stagefright 1.2) the video has several problems:

1. The option to go full-screen does not work
2. The video duration says 1:40 when it is actually 2:00
3. The video sometimes fails to start and you have to reload page
4. The video reliably distorts (tears and pixelates) at transition points when switching the underlying `.ts` streams.

Some of this is ameliorated if I don't use `HTML5`'s  tag.  But problem #4 remains.

I can play other `m3u8`'s on Stagefright without any of the above problems, so I am assuming my transmuxing code is wrong, but even forgoing it and using the (recently added) `HLS` segmenting features of `ffmpeg` I have the same problem. Recoding with `libx264` changes nothing.

I am at wit's end debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

Android's libstagefright (along with mediaservice's NuPlayer) is not so mature product as vlc and a lot of troubles which are not present while using vlc are present in android it is much more vulnerable for any broken, corrupted, deviated content.

Such pixelation/macroblock artifacts are usually present while some frames where dropped (by android code or were lost) before decoding.

If those corruptions are present along with some green fields it might be a problem with synchronization of format change with a key frames (which might be a result of wrong implementation of source, or in part which notifies ANativeWindow about format change).
In corner case you might not get any green frames but crop/reolution would be deviated and pixelation might be visible).

What I would do:
1) Check for frame dropps
2) Check with some analyzer frames at the borders of consecutive sections